# Cell of table (td) ignores span's and label's top/bottom margin/padding

Tags: html, css

I have an issue that any `span` and `label` have `margin` or `padding` as a child of `td` of the `table`.

This issue is the top and bottom margin got ignored inside the `td`, I mean the left and right padding works and the element get the top and bottom too but `td` hide the `margin-top`, `padding-top`, `margin-bottom` and `padding-bottom` inside it do not resize the cell height automatically, it is respecting top and bottom margins or paddings, it is acting like you have `overflow: hidden` for that `td` with fixed `height`.

The following JSFiddle links show the full code and case :

- Padding: http://jsfiddle.net/0f4jzdmk/1/
- Margin: http://jsfiddle.net/0f4jzdmk/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a simple solution, it is to add change the `display` of the `inline` elements to `inline-block`, seems the `td` height not read the top/bottom  margin/padding of inline children.

change the style like this :

```
span {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0f4jzdmk/3/